# Number theory / division algorithm

Tags: number-theory

A par number is a integer n such that 2|n , a odd number is a integer that is not par. We said that the par Numbers have a parity 0 and odd Numbers parity 1.

Assume that $z$ belong to the integers and that $n \ge 1$ is a natural number.

Show that $z$ and $z^n$ have the same parity using mathematical induction.

Comment: It will improve your Question if you mention how you tried to approach the problem, and what difficulty you encountered in trying it.

Comment: I made a direct demonstration with the assumption that z is par. I can not find a way to prove by induction with assumption that z is odd

Comment: What can you say about the product of two odd numbers?

Comment: @KatsuraSarutobi you should improve your question. Use [edit] and give use more informations, what you tried and what is hard for you.

Comment: A par number is a integer n such that 2|n , a odd number is a integer that is not par. We said that the par Numbers have a parity 0 and odd Numbers parity 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hints :

- The base case is obvious
- Use the rules $0*0=0$ and $1*1=1$ and the definition of a power
- parity means the value modulo $2$

Answer (score 0):

I have a proof for a case odd

Suppose that z is odd , namely 
z = 2k + 1

Then we have to proof that

If z = 2k + 1 then (z)^n = (2k + 1)^n is odd

For induction:

**Base case :**

P(0) = (z)^0 = (2k + 1)^0 
        = 1      = 1

**inductive step **

If p(s) then p(s+1) namely

Induction hypothesis (I.H) : z^s = (2k + 1) is  odd

We have to proof that 
z^s+1 = (2k + 1)^s+1 is odd

We have that
 z^s+1 = (2k+1)^s . (2k+1)
 For I.H (2k + 1) is odd

And we know for definition of odd Numbers that 2k + 1 is odd

So , the product of two odd Numbers is always odd.

And in conclusión we have that
z^s+1 = (2k + 1)^s+1 is odd  and therefore (z)^n = (2k + 1)^n is odd